# How to scroll to the top of the terminal buffer with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

Is there a keyboard command to scroll to the very top of the terminal buffer?

The closest command I could find is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd>, which only scrolls up one page of text at a time.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At least for `gnome-terminal`, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd> should do it (and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>END</kbd> to return to the bottom of the buffer).

Comment: +1; also works for `terminator`.

Comment: also works for `mate-terminal`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are referring to a session like an ssh/putty. In that case, AFAIK, no. As an aside, CTRL-ALT PgUp or PgDn will let you scroll one line at a time.